# java.lang.illegalstateexception: 'current page not finished!'

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin.android, stream

after all my trials to create a pdf with a table that contains Arabic text using itext7 failed, I decided to move to the normal way, where I use view.draw and save the result in a pdf. but this also didn't work. here's the code:

```
 Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf_new = new Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument();
            Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo_new = new Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(6000, 6000, 0).Create();
            Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument.Page page_new = pdf_new.StartPage(pageInfo_new);
            ListView listView = new ListView(this.Context);
            accounts_info_homeadapter hmm = new accounts_info_homeadapter(this, pdflist);
            listView.Adapter = hmm;
            listView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua);
            listView.Draw(page_new.Canvas);
            // lst.Draw(page.Canvas);
            //TextView txt = new TextView(this.Context);
            //txt.Text = "hi";
            //txt.Draw(page.Canvas);
            var path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            file_Path = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "Client.pdf");
            new_stream = new FileStream(file_Path, FileMode.Create);
            new_stream.Flush();
            pdf_new.WriteTo(new_stream);

            new_stream.Close();
            pdf_new.Close();
```

I got the exception: `java.lang.illegalstateexception: 'current page not finished!'` though I tried this a week ago on a trial list and it was working. now i'm getting this. I thought it might be the size of the pdf so I started increasing it but in vain. I tried changing my variables' names, I thought maybe because I tried to use them with my itext before, but still nothing. I deleted the fragment I 'm working on and then recreated it, also nothing. anyone know what the problem is. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one line. You forgot to close the page after editing it.

```
pdf_new.finishPage(page_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must finish the page by calling finishPage(page) before closing the page otherwise it will throw an exception.

From *close()* docs reference:

> Do not call this method if the page returned by startPage(android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument.PageInfo) is not finished by calling finishPage(android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument.Page).

In your case it should be:

```
pdf_new.finishPage(page_new);
pdf_new.close();
```

Source: [close() method docs reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument#close())

Answer (score -1):

**After inserting your desired text in the canvas make sure to place this line of code.
This helped me to remove my error**

```
canvas.drawText("Financial Statement for 2021",40,50,myPaint);
myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage1); //this one
```